# C# regex to parse /simple1/1.2-SNAPSHOT/

Tags: c#, regex

I need to find the last two values at the end of such a string, "simple1" and "1.2-SNAPSHOT" in the sample url below. But my code below (try to get simple1/1.2-SNAPSHOT/)  doesn't work, can anyone help?

http://localhost:8060/nexus/service/local/repositories/snapshots/content/org/sonatype/mavenbook/simple1/1.2-SNAPSHOT/

```
List<string> artifacts = new List<string>(); // this is already foler URL
            // store all URLs to the artifacts be deleted           
            artifacts = nexusAPI.findArtifacts(repository, contents, days, pattern);

 var regex = new Regex(".*\\/(.*\\/.*\\/)$");

            foreach (string url in artifacts)
            {                
                Console.WriteLine("group/artifact: {0}", regex.Matches(url));                
            }
```

Comment: *Must* you use regex?  This is a good case for string.LastIndexOf + string.Substring, or even just string.Split.

Comment: Use `str.Trim('/').Split('/')` and grab the 2 items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just split the string on '/' and get the last two parts. The regex isn't going to do anything more then that.

Comment: string[] ss = url.Split('/');
                int size = ss.Length;
                Console.WriteLine("version: {0}", ss[size-2]);
                Console.WriteLine("artifact: {0}", ss[size-3]);

Comment: @JirongHu - error checking ? Split on `one/two/three` would probably give different results than `one/two/three/ `

Answer (score 0):

If you *must* use RegEx, you're encountering an issue in that regexes are greedy - that means it puts as much in each .* as it possibly can.  So your first step is to make the regex not greedy.  Simply use this as your pattern:

```
(.*?)/
```

[Here's](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(.*%3F)%2F&i=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8060%2Fnexus%2Fservice%2Flocal%2Frepositories%2Fsnapshots%2Fcontent%2Forg%2Fsonatype%2Fmavenbook%2Fsimple1%2F1.2-SNAPSHOT%2F) a simple test showing how that this works.

This tells the regex to look for any character up to the slash, and then stop.

When you call `Regex.Matches(url, "(.*?)/")`, you will get returned an array of the matching data.  From there, you can just look at the last two elements.

Of course, as SledgeHammer mentioned, this is one case where regex is unnecessary and even cumbersome.  Simply working with `url.Split(new char[] {'/'})` will give you the results you need.